# Binding ViewModel to ViewController (ReactiveCocoa) iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

i am implementing simple facebook/google login for now. But trying to apply MVVM pattern with ReactiveCocoa in my project. I am not able to bind the viewModel with viewControllers . Tried CocoaActions but not able to make it work.

View Model :

```
let name = MutableProperty<String>("")
let email = MutableProperty<String>("")
let phoneNo = MutableProperty<String>("")
let referal = MutableProperty<String>("")

var fbLoginAction:Action<OnboardingViewController,Bool,NSError>
```

View Controller :

```
        //MARK: Signup Binding
    let loginCocoaAction = CocoaAction(viewModel.fbLoginAction., input:())
    signupView.fbBtn.addTarget(loginCocoaAction, action: CocoaAction.selector, forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 1):

Its been a while since this question was posted. Since then, [RAC 5.0.0](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/releases/tag/5.0.0) has been released which makes this a lot easier, thanks to UI Bindings:

Assuming, you have `fbLoginAction` ready as defined in the View Model, you can bind this action to a button in the View Controller like this:

```
signupView.fbBtn.reactive.pressed = CocoaAction(fbLoginAction, input: self)
```

Your original problem was probably because you provided `()` as input, but the input of your `fbLoginAction` is defined as `OnboardingViewController`.

Depends on whether you actually meant to do that and need the `OnboardingViewController` as input to the `fbLoginAction`, you can do it as posted above with `input: self`, or if you don't actually need the input, you can change it to

```
let fbLoginAction:Action<(),Bool,NSError>
```

and

```
signupView.fbBtn.reactive.pressed = CocoaAction(fbLoginAction)
```